# UnBoundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment (Python)

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment, local

I'm trying to create a function `servo_to_quadrant` that returns the value `servo_quadrant`.

Questions similar to this one have involved there being an issue with a global variable outside of the function. I don't think that's the issue in this case, as the variable is only needed from within the function (although I could be wrong).

Code:

```
def servo_to_quadrant(servo_val):
    if servo_val < 0: 360 + servo_val
    if servo_val >= 360: servo_val = servo_val - 360
    if servo_val >= 0 and servo_val < 90: servo_quadrant = 1
    if servo_val >= 90 and servo_val < 180: servo_quadrant = 2
    if servo_val >= 180 and servo_val < 270: servo_quadrant = 3
    if servo_val >= 270 and servo_val < 360: servo_quadrant = 4
    return servo_quadrant

servo_val = -30
quadrant = servo_to_quadrant(servo_val)
print(quadrant)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    quadrant = servo_to_quadrant(servo_val)
  File "test2.py", line 8, in servo_to_quadrant
    return servo_quadrant
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'servo_quadrant' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Just initialize it to some value at the start of function. Like this `servo_quadrant = 0`

Comment: Probably you can just return required values instead of using servo_quadrant variable. Like `if servo_val < 0: return 360 + servo_val`

Comment: Zlopez - `servo_quadrant = 0` seems to return `0`, as though it skips over all of the if functions.

artemdevel - I'm trying to extrapolate the quadrant that `servo_val` falls into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you have assigned the variable `servo_quadrant` under one of the preceding `if` conditions in your function, and if none of the conditions return True, you will haven't any `servo_quadrant`. For getting  ride of this problem you need to initial this variable in your function.

You can put `servo_quadrant = 0` on top level of your function or you can check the value of the `servo_quadrant` before you return anything :

```
if servo_quadrant :
    return servo_quadrant
return None
```

Also *Note* that you need to reassign variable `servo_val` :

```
if servo_val < 0: servo_val=360 + servo_val
```

Demo:

```
def servo_to_quadrant(servo_val):
    servo_quadrant=0
    if servo_val < 0: servo_val=360 + servo_val
    if servo_val >= 360: servo_val = servo_val - 360
    if servo_val >= 0 and servo_val < 90: servo_quadrant = 1
    if servo_val >= 90 and servo_val < 180: servo_quadrant = 2
    if servo_val >= 180 and servo_val < 270: servo_quadrant = 3
    if servo_val >= 270 and servo_val < 360: servo_quadrant = 4
    return servo_quadrant

servo_val = -30
quadrant = servo_to_quadrant(servo_val)
print quadrant
```

Result:

```
4
```

Comment: I've added `servo_quadrant = 0` in the first line of the function, but it seems to return 0 - as though it has skipped over the if statements.The first two if statements modify `servo_val` to be within the ranges 0 to 360, in order to work with the if statements that follow.

Comment: @l87q4t you need to reassign it in your first `if` : so change the condition to `servo_val=360 + servo_val`

Comment: oops...silly me. It works now (without needing `servo_quadrant=0`). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you try to modify servo_quadrant which isn't defined in your function. Python uses global scope by default if you just read a variable. So if you don't modify it everything will work fine. If you need to modify it just add `global servo_quadrant` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: Does adding `global servo_quadrant` mean that it becomes a global variable? I was hoping to keep it local to the function, as I intend to run multiple instances of the function at once (this code is part of a larger code).

Comment: yes, it will be in a global scope, in your case it is better to initialize it to some value as mentioned in other comments.

Comment: Others have pointed out that the problem was that I forgot to add the code that would modify `servo_val` to fit within 0 and 360 (in the first two if statements), but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you assign `servo_quadrant` in every path through your function before you try and return it.

```
def servo_to_quadrant(servo_val):
    if servo_val < 0: 360 + servo_val # <--- This does nothing
    if servo_val >= 360: servo_val = servo_val - 360 # <--- This assumes servo_val < 720
    if servo_val >= 0 and servo_val < 90: servo_quadrant = 1
    if servo_val >= 90 and servo_val < 180: servo_quadrant = 2
    if servo_val >= 180 and servo_val < 270: servo_quadrant = 3
    if servo_val >= 270 and servo_val < 360: servo_quadrant = 4
    # At this point, servo_quadrant may still not have been assigned
    return servo_quadrant
```

If you want to move `servo_val` into the range `0<=servo_val<360`, you can use the modulo operator.
And you can take advantage of the fact that if you return from a function, you don't need to keep checking the same conditions.

```
def servo_to_quadrant(servo_val):
    servo_val %= 360
    if servo_val < 90: return 1
    if servo_val < 180: return 2
    if servo_val < 270: return 3
    return 4
```

Comment: I added the first two if statements in order to modify `servo_val` so that it's value is within 0 and 360 in order to work with the if functions that follow it.

Comment: This line: `if servo_val < 0: 360 + servo_val` is not modifying `servo_val`.  This line: `if servo_val >= 360: servo_val = servo_val - 360` doesn't necessarily move `servo_val` into the expected range, unless you know that `servo_val` can't be more than 720.

Comment: I should have paid more attention. Thanks though.