# Reverse Words in String using Python

Tags: python, string, reverse

```
class Solution(object):
    def reverseWords(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        d=[]

        words=s.split()
        for i in words:
            d.append(i[::-1])
            print d
            result=" ".join(d)
        return result
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

Edit:-

```
result=" ".join(d)
print result
```

When I used this code in the last two lines I can see my stdout but null value is being returned and when I used these two lines in place of above:

```
result=" ".join(d)
return result
```

I get only the first word of the line.

Ex. "I am writing a code"

Expected output:- "edoc a gnitirw ma I "
Actual output: "edoc"

Comment: What exactly is your question? What research have you done? What value of `s` was used that got the error message? (In particular, was it the empty string?)

Comment: [Works on my machine](https://ideone.com/ErBgj2).

Comment: Your code does not raise any exceptions in my python.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533098/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-python

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you declared `result` only inside your loop. If you send an empty string, `s.split()` will return an empty list and `result` will never be declared.

Declare `result` also before the `for` loop with a default value and this exception should go away.

Comment: I tried that too but I got an error saying 'output limit exceeded'. I tried this on leetcode.